# How can the spectrum of $A = \frac{d}{dx}$ in $C(\mathbb{R})$ be equal to $\mathbb{R}$, as for every $\lambda$ there exists a resolvent $R(\lambda)g$?

Tags: operator-theory, spectral-theory

Let's now find the eigenvalues of $A$ (which are the spectrum):

$$A f = \lambda f$$

$$f' = \lambda f$$

$$f' - \lambda f = 0$$

$$\Rightarrow \quad f(x) = C \cdot e^{\lambda x} \quad \Rightarrow \quad \forall \ \lambda \in \mathbb{R} \quad f \in C(\mathbb{R}) \quad \Rightarrow \quad \sigma (A) = \mathbb{R}$$

Now let's find the resolvent:

$$(A -  \lambda I)f = g$$

$$f' - \lambda f = g$$

$$e^{- \lambda x}f' - \lambda e^{- \lambda x}f = e^{- \lambda x} g$$ $$(e^{-\lambda x} f)' = e^{-\lambda x}g$$ $$e^{-\lambda x}f(x) - e^{-\lambda a} f(a) = \int_a^x e^{-\lambda x}g(x) dx$$ $$R(\lambda)g(x) = f(x) = e^{\lambda x} \int_a^x e^{-\lambda x} g(x) dx + e^{\lambda (x-a)} f(a) \quad \Rightarrow \quad \forall \ \lambda \in \mathbb{R} \quad f \in C(\mathbb{R})$$

But because our spectrum is equal to $\mathbb{R}$, this **should** mean that for no $\lambda \in \mathbb{R}$ there exists a resolvent $R(\lambda)g(x)$ (as the spectrum is also the set for which $(A - \lambda I)$ is not invertible i.e. for which the resolvent doesn't exist)

Am I mixing up definitions here? I'm really confused

Comment: Note that you must not only prove that the inverse of $A-\lambda I$ exists, but also that it is a bounded operator.

Comment: What is your norm for $C(\mathbb{R})$?

Comment: @DisintegratingByParts Why should this be important, what norm I have for $C(\mathbb{R})$? Sry if that's a silly question, we just started spectral theory

Comment: @anon : The norm matters because a resolvent must be bounded, by definition. So the norm can change the spectrum.

Answer (score 3):

Several things to unpack here.

- The spectrum does not consists of the eigenvalues alone. It does in finite-dimension, but in general there is more stuff. The spectrum consists of those $\lambda$ such that $T-\lambda I$ is invertible and **bounded**, which is why what norm you use matters.
- You have an operator $A:C^1(\mathbb R)\to C(\mathbb R)$. That is, your operator is unbounded with domain $C^1(\mathbb R)$.
- Final comment: if you have no norm nor topology, you are not doing Functional Analysis nor Operator Theory.
- If the domain is all of $C^1(\mathbb R)$, then indeed every $\lambda\in\mathbb R$ is an eigenvalue.
- If there exist functions $f$ with $(A-\lambda I)f=0$, you cannot expect it to have an inverse.
- So, what's the problem? Your formula for $R(\lambda)$ uses the value $f(a)$. But $R(\lambda)$ has to evaluate on $g$; how are you supposed to know $f(a)$?
- The answer to the above question is, **you don't**. In these situations one usually restricts the domain, for example with the condition $f(0)=0$. Now the equation $f'-\lambda f$ has only the solution $C=0$, so no $\lambda$ is an eigenvalue. Your $R(\lambda)$ now works, and so the spectrum of $A$ is empty.
- More importantly, your $R(\lambda)$ requires $f(a)=0$ to be linear.
- If instead you want to leave the domain as all of $C^1(\mathbb R)$, you argue correctly that $A-\lambda I$ has nontrivial kernel, and so it cannot be invertible. The spectrum is then $\mathbb R$.

---

**More detail:** You say that "$f(a)$ is just a constant". Which it is. But you cannot relate it to $g$. So let us just write $c$ instead of $f(a)$. Then
$$\tag1
R_\lambda(g)(x)=e^{\lambda x}\int_a^xe^{-\lambda t} g(t)\,dt+ce^{\lambda(x-a)}.
$$
We immediately have a problem, because $R_\lambda$ is supposed to be linear, but here $R_\lambda (0)=ce^{\lambda(x-a)}$.

Still, let us assume we didn't notice that and we keep thinking.
$R_\lambda$  is supposed to be the inverse of $A-\lambda I$, so let us check.  It is easy to see that
$$
(A-\lambda I)\circ R_\lambda (g) = g. 
$$
But
\begin{align}
R_\lambda\circ (A-\lambda I)\,g
&=e^{\lambda x}\,\int_a^x e^{-\lambda t}\big(g'(t)-\lambda g(t)\big)\,dt+ce^{\lambda(x-a)}\\[0.3cm]
&=e^{\lambda x}\,\bigg[e^{-\lambda t}g(t)\Big|_a^x+\lambda\int_a^xe^{-\lambda t}g(t)\,dt-\lambda\int_a^xe^{-\lambda t}g(t)\,dt\bigg]+ce^{\lambda(x-a)}\\[0.3cm]
&=g(x)+\big(c-g(a)\big)\,e^{\lambda(x-a)}. 
\end{align}
To get $g(x)$ as the result, we would need to have $c=g(a)$. But this is a computation of $R_\lambda\circ (A-\lambda I)$, so $R_\lambda$ does not "see" $g$, it only "sees" $(A-\lambda I)g$. So we would need to somehow deduce $g(0)$ from knowing $g'-\lambda g$. Which is not possible unless you prescribe it, since $g'-\lambda g$ admits a solution for every choice of $g(0)$.

In summary:

- if you set the domain of $A$ to be all of $C^1(\mathbb R)$, then $A$ has every $\lambda\in\mathbb R$ as an eigenvalue. Which means that the resolvent does not exist. The $R_\lambda$ you wrote is not an inverse for $A-\lambda I$. You can see this very clearly if you take $\lambda=1$, $g(x)=e^x$. Then $(A-I)g=0$, and $R_\lambda\circ (A-\lambda I)g=g$ if we choose $c=1$. But if for instance we take $g(x)=\sin x$, then
  $$
  R_\lambda\circ(A-\lambda I)g=R_\lambda (\cos t-\sin t)=e^x+\sin x\ne g.
  $$
  That is, the constant $c$ can be arranged to work for some functions, but it will fail for others. $R_\lambda$ does not exist as an inverse for $A-\lambda I$. So in this situation $\sigma(A)=\mathbb R$ and the resolvent does not exist for any $\lambda$.
- If we set the domain of $A$ to be $D(A)=\{f\in C^1(\mathbb R): \ f(0)=0\}$ then $f'-\lambda f$ only has the solution $0$, so no $\lambda$ is an eigenvalue. But in this situation
  $$
  R_\lambda g=e^{\lambda x}\int_0^xe^{-\lambda t}\,g(t)\,dt
  $$
  and in this situation $R_\lambda\circ(A-\lambda I)=(A-\lambda I)\circ R_\lambda=\operatorname{id}$ on the domain of $A$. So $\sigma(A)=\emptyset$.
- If we (try to) set the domain of $A$ to be $D(A)=\{f\in C^1(\mathbb R): \ f(0)=1\}$ (or any other nonzero constant) now this is not even a subpsace.
- **And the most important conclusion:** operator theory is analysis, not algebra. The spectrum is close to useless as a purely algebraic object. One considers operators acting on normed spaces, so there is a topology hanging around. And the concept of "invertible" depends on the topology you are using. Those things cannot be ignored. Changing the topology will likely change the spectrum.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. However, what I'm asking here is basically: If the spectrum of $A$ is empty, then how should $R(\lambda)$ exist as - because the spectrum of $A$ is empty - for no $\lambda \in \mathbb{R}$ there exists a resolvent $R(\lambda$)? The same for the last point: How is it possible for $(A - \lambda I)$ to be non-invertible if the spectrum of $A$ is equal to $\mathbb{R}$? This is what I'm asking about, because we've been taught that the "spectrum is the set of $\lambda$ for which $(A - \lambda I)$ is not invertible" (which is the set of eigenvalues as those give you...

Comment: ...non-trivial kernels, i.e. $(A - \lambda I) f = 0 \quad \Rightarrow \quad \forall \ \lambda \in \sigma(A) \ f \neq 0$). But here, we get that (for $f(0) = 0$ e.g.) the set of eigenvalues is the empty set, but $R(\lambda)$ exists for all $\lambda \in \mathbb{R}$. But we already have found out that $(A - \lambda I)$ is non-invertible (as the spectrum of $A$ is the empty set), so how can it still be invertible i.e. the resolvent $R(\lambda)$ exists for all $\lambda \in \mathbb{R}$? Maybe I'm mixing up definitions here?

Comment: You are mixing several things that I addressed in the answer. If the spectrum is empty then $A-\lambda I$ is invertible. More precisely, $A-\lambda I$ is invertible if and only if $\lambda\not\in\sigma(A)$; that's the definition of the spectrum. The spectrum contains the eigenvalues, but there is usually more. Invertible means injective, surjective, and the inverse has to be bounded; if $\lambda$ is an eigenvalue it means that $A-\lambda I$ is not injective, but it could be injective and still fail to be invertible. Finally, $R(\lambda)$ exists $\iff$ $\lambda\not\in\sigma(A)$.

Comment: So where's the mistake in my calculations? I showed that $\sigma (A) = \mathbb{R}$, but I also showed that for any $\lambda$, $R(\lambda)$ exists (which should mean, that the spectrum is empty, but it's not as I've showed it in the first part of my calculations)

Comment: No you didn't. Please read my answer. "$f(a)$" is meaningless in your expression for $R(\lambda)$.

Comment: I literally don't understand this. $f(a)$ is just a constant, so why should it decide whether $R(\lambda)$ exists or not?

Comment: Maybe let me ask you this instead: For which $\lambda$ is $ R(\lambda)g(x) = e^{\lambda x} \int_a^x e^{-\lambda x} g(x) dx + e^{\lambda (x-a)} f(a)$ an element of $C^1 (\mathbb{R})$?

Comment: I wrote a bit (maybe too much), trying to explain the problems. But the main issue is that your $R(\lambda)$ is not even linear, unless your constant $f(a)$  is zero.  You cannot ignore domain issues, you cannot ignore topological issues.

Comment: Why is it important for the resolvent to be linear? First time hearing this

Comment: The inverse of a linear function is linear.